# PyQt5 Audio no response

Tags: audio, python-3.x, pyqt5

I am trying to make an audio player based on pyqt5 . hovewer reading the examples at the site packages and visiting also the [QAudioOutput strange peak sound at beginning in PyQt4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829184/qaudiooutput-strange-peak-sound-at-beginning-in-pyqt4) i couldn't make a step forward and it seems there is no audio output. Thanks in advance , this is my current code (python3.3)

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets, QtMultimedia

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):    
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        format = QtMultimedia.QAudioFormat()
        format.setSampleRate(44100)
        format.setSampleSize(16)
        format.setChannelCount(1)
        format.setCodec("audio/wav")
        format.setByteOrder(QtMultimedia.QAudioFormat.LittleEndian)
        format.setSampleType(QtMultimedia.QAudioFormat.SignedInt)
        self.output = QtMultimedia.QAudioOutput(QtMultimedia.QAudioDeviceInfo.defaultOutputDevice(), format, self)

        self.file=QtCore.QFile()
        self.file.setFileName("data/voicemail/99dc6d529c0c5d6b2ec5cda7b26cc1bb9af58bd4774d161f66186f62bf3093cd.wav")
        self.file.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly)
        self.file.seek(44)
        self.output.start(self.file)

        #self.file.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```